# How to convert string on format array to array

Tags: php, arrays, string, converters

I have a string variable in this format:

```
$array = '[{"name":"jack","address":"who knows"},{"name":"jill","address":"who knows too"}]';
```

how can I get value from

```
$array[0]['name']; //value is 'jack'
```

Comment: try json_decode($array,true);

Comment: Do you 100% control where that `$array` value come from? If this is the case you can use `eval`.

Comment: ok thanks for your comment its working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://juderosario.com/2016/09/01/parsing-json-with-php/

ok I get it from there

```
$json = '[ {"id":"1", "name":"foo" }, {"id":"2", "name":"bar" } ]';
$baz = json_decode($json,true);

echo($baz[1]['name']); //bar
```

Comment: The format of your input is not the same as the one you posted in your question.

Comment: i can change that string, I only need how the string can be an array